# Android JSON Parsing Crashing Application AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am using a JSON parser to read the data from my JSON file and display it within my app, I was originally using this code to create arrays which works fine but now I have pasted it into a new application to make it get data from the JSON and put it onto a text field which isn't working. I will post the code and error log below.

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class TechnicianProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String url;
    private String TAG = SearchScreen.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_technician_profile);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String username = bundle.getString("username");
        String userid = bundle.getString("userid");

        setTitle("Technician - " + username);
        url = "http://curtisboylan.me/mygeek/mygeekprofile.php?user=" + userid;

        Log.d("test", url);

        new GetProfile().execute();

    }
    private class GetProfile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TechnicianProfile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MyGeek");
                    TextView usernametext;
                    // looping through All Contacts

                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
                        usernametext = (TextView) TechnicianProfile.this.findViewById(R.id.abouttext);
                        usernametext.setText(c.getString("name"));
                        // username.add(c.getString("name"));
                        // userid.add(c.getString("id"));
                        // location.add(c.getString("location"));
                        // reviewscore.add(c.getString("reviewscore"));
                        //  price.add(c.getString("price"));
                        // urllist.add(c.getString("url"));




                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> D/test: http://curtisboylan.me/mygeek/mygeekprofile.php?user=1
>   E/EGL_emulation: tid 2593: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0x91199f00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH E/EGL_emulation: tid 2593:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8f2f5000,
>   error=EGL_BAD_MATCH E/SearchScreen: Response from url:
>   {"MyGeek":[{"id":"1","name":"Curtis Boylan","location":"Swords, Co
>   Dublin","reviewscore":"5.6","url":"https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/11062691_831452480236559_1123476984274233173_n.jpg?oh=8eb4bb9519a2cd3b96b085146b0ae718&oe=596BBB5F","price":"30"}]}
>
> ```
>             --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>               Process: com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication, PID: 2416
>               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
> ```
>
> original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6891)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1083)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5205)
>                         at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13656)
>                         at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13620)
>                         at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13604)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7347)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4480)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4337)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4312)
>                         at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianProfile$GetProfile.doInBackground(TechnicianProfile.java:72)
>                         at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianProfile$GetProfile.doInBackground(TechnicianProfile.java:39)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)  E/EGL_emulation: tid 2593: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0x8f2f5080, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH E/WindowManager:
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianProfile has leaked
>   window DecorView@415df5e[] that was originally added here
>                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
>                        at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianProfile$GetProfile.onPreExecute(TechnicianProfile.java:48)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)
>                        at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianProfile.onCreate(TechnicianProfile.java:36)
>                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianListView has leaked
>   window DecorView@b6a1d55[] that was originally added here
>                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
>                        at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianListView$GetContacts.onPreExecute(TechnicianListView.java:78)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)
>                        at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianListView.initViews(TechnicianListView.java:67)
>                        at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.TechnicianListView.onCreate(TechnicianListView.java:48)
>                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do any UI operation in `doInBackground`.

Put set text related stuff in `onPostExecute`method of `AsyncTask`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove UI component from doInBackground and  update UI in postExecute method of Asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify a View from a background thread.
View Android UI in not thread safe, and so can only be modified from the main thread.

The offence is this line in your `doInBackground()`

```
usernametext.setText(c.getString("name"));
```

Instead, you should return the found String from the `doInBackground`, override `onPostExecute` and set it there.
An other option is wrap is in a `runOnUiThread()` but honestly that's more complicated and unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use

```
usernametext = (TextView) TechnicianProfile.this.findViewById(R.id.abouttext);
                        usernametext.setText(c.getString("name"));
```

from .doInbackground() method, because this method is executed on background thread, but UI elements can only be changed from a main thread.
Move UI update to .onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest "Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException" you are doing wrong thing in wrong thread. Please move your `setText` code to `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate`.

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class TechnicianProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String url;
    private String TAG = SearchScreen.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private TextView usernametext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_technician_profile);
        usernametext = (TextView) TechnicianProfile.this.findViewById(R.id.abouttext);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String username = bundle.getString("username");
        String userid = bundle.getString("userid");

        setTitle("Technician - " + username);
        url = "http://curtisboylan.me/mygeek/mygeekprofile.php?user=" + userid;

        Log.d("test", url);

        new GetProfile(usernametext).execute();

    }



    private class GetProfile extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    private TextView tv;
        public GetProfile(TextView tv) {
            this.tv = tv;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TechnicianProfile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MyGeek");

                    // looping through All Contacts

                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(0);
                        String str = c.getString("name");
                        publishProgress(str);

                        // username.add(c.getString("name"));
                        // userid.add(c.getString("id"));
                        // location.add(c.getString("location"));
                        // reviewscore.add(c.getString("reviewscore"));
                        //  price.add(c.getString("price"));
                        // urllist.add(c.getString("url"));




                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      tv.setText(values[0]);
    }
    }
}
```